# Import scipy into pycharm, already changed project interpreter, unused import statement

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, anaconda

I have imported numpy in properly but can't seem to get scipy working. I am using anaconda as the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to be more specific. You can:

- Post your code
- Explain what you are trying to do with the code
- Post the error

There are thousands of ways a module can not properly work. Your question is simply impossible to understand.